# migrating from webpack to vite, the resources images are not loaded

Tags: laravel, webpack, vite

I want to migrate my SPA (laravel 9 with Vue3) from laravel-mix (webpack) to vite.

I have done all the settings .... but I am not sure how to convert the existing webpack.mix.js to vite.config.js

The old webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

const path = require('path')

 

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')

    .extract()

    .vue({version: 3})

    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')

    .setResourceRoot(process.env.MIX_BASE_URL)

    .webpackConfig({

        output: {

            publicPath: process.env.MIX_BASE_URL

        }

    })

    .version()

 

mix.alias({

    '@main_app': path.join(__dirname, 'resources/js'),   

})
```

The new vite.config.js

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
           input: ['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {                   
                    base: '/app_name/',                   
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@main_app': '/resources/js',
        }
    }
});
```

When run

```
npm run dev
```

the app loads but not the resources... images, bootstrap-icons,

The base url in .env:

```
APP_URL=https://localhost/app_name
VITE_ASSET_URL="${APP_URL}"
VITE_BASE_URL="/app_name/"
```

I also tried the VITE_ASSET_URL in the vite.config.js

```
transformAssetUrls: {                   
                    base: 'https://localhost/app_name',                   
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
```

but the resources are still trying to load from (which is 404)

```
http://localhost/assets/images/logo.png
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/app_name/assets/images/logo.png
```

The images in vue files template are loaded using relative path:

```
<img src="../../assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
```

**UPDATE**

the images are loading if set null for the base

```
transformAssetUrls: {                   
   base: null,
   includeAbsolute: false
}
```

but the bootstrap icons are not.

In app.scss I am using this:

```
@import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons'
```

**UPDATE 2**

the fonts now are loading.... I have to specify the exact file name extension

```
@import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css'
```

The other ptoblem that I have now is when build the app.

It creates a folder build in public.

How can I tell to put all the build content in public not build folder ?

AND...even if I let the build folder....the data is loaded from localhost/build/assets.... instead of localhost/app_name/build/assets....

**UPDATE 3**
I fixed also the assets problem...

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#custom-base-urls

You have to set in .env

```
ASSET_URL="${APP_URL}"
```